# select2 required and default notification

Tags: jquery-select2

I;m using select2 with a required field. When the field is not filled out, in Chrome the notification that it's a required field is out of place. In FF, I can't even see the notification, so it just prevents the form from being submitted.

any ideas how to resolve this?